# Download files directly to my server

Tags: http, ftp, web-hosting

Is there a way to download files directly to my web host? Let's say I want to download a video file from a site and upload it in to my website again. Instead of downloading it to my PC and uploading, Is there a way to do that easily?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can connect with ssh to your server, you can use the `wget` command to do download a file. (`cUrl`does this also I think)

Comment: I have ssh to my server. Can you please tell me how to log in?

Comment: If you're on Linux on your machine then enter `ssh user@hostname` where user is your username on the server and 'hostname' is the name of the server (you can also use the IP address). If you're on Windows, download "Putty", and create a new connection to your server. Once your're connected to the server, type `wget http://www.anywebsite.com/files/myvideo.avi` and the video at this URL will be download in your current directory. If you don't know much about Linux command-line I strongly recommand you to read tutorials about that they are legions on the Internet :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. My web host asked me to connect via SSH and then I asked their help. Finally they said they don't have SSH access for shared hosting :(.

Comment: Well I don't see how you can download on your serveur directly... Maybe some trick in PHP or something like that could do it but I don't know :-/

Comment: Thanks again for the hint. I should try php ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this script now :)

`

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();

// folder to save downloaded files to. must end with slash
$destination_folder = 'downloads/';

$url = $_POST['url'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$ext = $_POST['extention'];

$newfname = $destination_folder . $name . '.' . $ext;

$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
  $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

  if ($newf)
  while(!feof($file)) {
    fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
  }
}

if ($file) {
  fclose($file);
}

if ($newf) {
  fclose($newf);
}

echo 'File saved as '. $newfname
```

?>`